# How to scrub a document of all text between brackets with find and replace

Tags: windows, find-and-replace, multiple-instances

I have a log file and I need to find all instances of `<password>` hash here `</password>` and remove the hash and replace it with some dummy text like aaa-aaa-aaa-aaaa.

The recurring search argument is anything that matches a bracket that starts with `<password>` and ends with `</password>`. All the hashes being replaced will be different.

What's the easiest way to go a bout this? The log is on a windows machine. Probably easiest would be to use MS word for me, unless it's achievable with wordpad, notepad, or some other light weight editor like textpad.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDownload.html) (very lightweight), but any editor that supports regular expressions should be fine.

Use the replace feature ->

```
 Find what - <password>.*</password>
 Replace with - <password>helloWorld</password>
```

Regular expression - yes

Comment: textpad can also do this.

Answer (score 0):

FARt.exe

```
 http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/
```

Command line for you

```
 fart "filepath"  "<password> hash here </password>" "<password>sdasdadaasd</password>"
```